VS Code shows Spring Boot packages does not exist, even though it still runs the Java application
This is a project I cloned from GitHub (my friend initialized the Spring Boot project and everything).
However, my VS Code shows that it does not recognize all of the Spring Boot packages and other stuff as well including Jakarta, Hibernate, Lombok. I attached a picture of the errors here:
VS Code shows problem with Spring Boot packages. When I hit Run Java, the project still runs fine but those squiggly red underlines are annoying and recently I have some other problems with the code logic, so I want to get rid of those errors first to ensure the problems are not form the dependencies.
I installed maven extension as recommended from VS Code.
Some methods I tried:

I checked the dependencies in pom.xml. The pom.xml file is below. It has maven plugin, spring-boot-starter, it uses java 17, I have jdk 21

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.auction.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-streams-auction</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kafka-streams-auction</name>
    <description>Kafka Streams project for auction Web app backend</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <kafka.version>3.7.0</kafka.version>
        <ehcache.version>3.10.8</ehcache.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.5.Final</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${ehcache.version}</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.32</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
 </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


I removed maven paths in setting ( hope that it will automatically look for the files it needs in the project) and
I enabled anything in the maven setting VS Code Maven setting
Didn't work, and I switched to

    "java.configuration.maven.userSettings": "./.m2/wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.9.5-bin/32db9c34/apache-maven-3.9.5/conf/settings.xml",
    "java.configuration.maven.globalSettings": "./.m2/wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.9.5-bin/32db9c34/apache-maven-3.9.5/conf/settings.xml"


I tried


Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace
as suggested in an old post.


I tried mvn clean install and chose Reload projects.

This post suggested to change the wrapper folder but it was in Eclipse/Intellij package does not exist
So, I guessed the equivalent in VS Code was the executable path, and that was already set in my vs code (I cannot modify it).
/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk/maven/latest/bin/mvn

I initialized a separate Spring Boot project and the Spring Boot packages were recognized in that new project. So, I wonder if the problem was because GitHub excluded some folders and I missed these folders when I cloned the project from GitHub (I tried to cloned the project a few times though, and my friend also cloned it without any similar problems). Though, I compared the new iniltialized project with the git cloned project and only saw the ./mvn/wrapper folder different, so I copied that folder to the git cloned project, but the errors were not resolved.
When I added another Spring Boot inside this git repository, this subproject had the same errors with unrecognized packages.


I am new with this Spring Boot so I am not sure what to look for now.
Any tips or explanation are greatly appreciated!

Try opening the directory where pom.xml is located in VSCode.

It's set with **/pom.xml
